# Define and plot constant function in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a constant function in python (this is not what I am actually trying to do but if I solve this it might be a first step).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def constant_function(x):
    return 2

t1 = np.arange(0.0,1.0,0.1)
plt.plot(t1,constant_function(t1))
```

However I get the error

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) your function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


@np.vectorize
def constant_function(x):
    return 2


t1 = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)
plt.plot(t1, constant_function(t1))
plt.show()
```

this way `constant_function(t1)` will return `[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]` (i.e. `[f(x[0]), f(x[1]), f(x[2]), ...]`) instead of just `2` and the dimensions will match.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you please explain why I usually do not need to vectorize the function (it is the first time I encounter this issue).

Comment: that depends on your function. if your function expects a sequence as argument and returns a sequence of the same size everything will work just fine. here you ignore the input and just return the scalar `2`.

Comment: I also like this solution for more advanced cases since it is a good yet simple demonstration of how `np.vectorize` works! Also +1

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion `vectorize` is overkill to plot a simple "function" which just yields a constant value, especially if basic python syntax is the source of the problem. (And imho decorators are quite more advanced than using simple numpy methods.)

Instead I'd recommend just setting the return value of the function to an array of the same shape:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def constant_function(x):
    return 2

t1 = np.arange(0.0,1.0,0.1)
plt.plot(t1, np.full(t1.shape, constant_function(t1)))
```

Since `constant_function` currently takes an argument which is not used, another improvement could be to construct the array inside `constant_function`, using the information from the argument `x`:

```
def constant_function(x):
    return np.full(x.shape, 2)

t1 = np.arange(0.0,1.0,0.1)
plt.plot(t1, constant_function(t1))
```

Comment: your second option is pretty elegant! +1

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than any np.full or vectorize: just define the constant functions as 0 * x + 2. This worked out for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(-8, 8, 200)

def const_func():
    return 0 * x + 2


plt.plot(x, const_func())
plt.show()
```